# Serial number using css

Tags: css

I am trying to use css to make the automatically show the serial number.

I am currently trying:

```css
p:nth-of-type(n):after
{
    content: n;
}
```

As shown in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/jWdrY/2), I would like the p tags to show 1, 2, 3, 4, such that if a `<p>` is added or removed using js, it would automatically reorder.

Comment: `p:nth-of-type(n):after{ content: '2';}` I think what you looking for is counters. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Counters

Comment: Sorry i had used 2 for testing. I meant to use n.

Comment: Don't be lazy and read the link I have provided. It's your answer :)

Comment: @Morpheus This works perfectly. Could you please enter the same as an answer so I could mark it as answered for others.

Comment: You can accept @Passerby's answer. It will save me typing and avoid duplicate answers.

Comment: @Morpheus To be fair I didn't look at your comment before posting my answer, it just need time to type that long; but then to be fair, your comment did come up before my answer, so it's totally OK for you to get the tick.

Comment: @Passerby I don't mind, because your answer is totally perfect to be accepted.

Comment: haha @Morpheus i wasnt lazy I was just answering your comment in parts. I was checking your jsfiddle update while writing the first comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use CSS [`counter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Counters) function:

```html
<div class="pCounted">
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

```css
div.pCounted
{
    counter-reset:paragraph;
}
div.pCounted p:after, /* CSS2 syntax */
div.pCounted p::after /* CSS3 syntax */
{
    counter-increment:paragraph;
    content: counter(paragraph);
}
```

[Online demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jWdrY/1/)

This function is [well supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-counters).